# Thread start method returns before run has returned

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

When I run my program, I see the below output -

`Type something
Hello
Hello
Hello` -

My question is why does the Type something statement even get printed? proc1.start() calls the run method, and since there is an infinite loop in the run method, it should never come out of the run method. Is Thread.sleep(100) causing this? Can someone please explain? I am clearly missing something simple here. Here is the code -

```
public class Processor extends Thread {
private boolean running = true;

public void run() {
    try {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void shutdown() {
    running = false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Processor proc1 = new Processor();
    proc1.start();

    System.out.println("Type something");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.nextLine();

    proc1.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title expresses what you think, incorrectly, should happen, not what is actually happening,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason "Type something" gets printed is because by calling `proc1.start()`, you are starting another `Thread`. This `Thread` runs *concurrently* with the main thread. So, in reality this snippet of code has 2 threads. The main thread is responsible for printing "Type something" and the Processor `Thread` is responsible for printing "Hello" every 100 seconds.

When you call `proc1.start()`, the line of code does *not* block on that line. Instead, the program will call that line, start `Processor` `Thread` and then keep running main.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of threads is to allow you to run code in parallel. So, just like you can start Excel while your music player is still running and playing your favorite tunes, your "Hello-loop" is executed in parallel with the rest of your program, i.e. the "Type something"-part. To stay with this analogy, your `proc1.start()` is the equivalent of launching Excel.

For an in-depth explanation, you can either read about the [Java Thread class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or have a look at this [Java Multithreading Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) or, for a more technical introduction, there is the [Lesson on Concurrency from the "official" Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

*A quick "buyer beware": Multi-threading and concurrency are extremely involved concepts that can lead to all sorts of difficult to trace errors in programs. Even dumb things like `a = a + 1` can fail if two threads in your program are accessing `a` simultaneously. You will probably need to do quite a bit of reading and experimenting.*

Comment: Agree, 1+. Also, as a side rec, perhaps running should be `volatile`.

Comment: Two. One for the main program and one for the "Hello-loop".

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

needs to be removed. If you just run the thread the compiler won't have time to print the "type something" line before the thread begins its infinite loop. Threads work in tandem with the main method not against it.

Comment: Not true! Your computer has multiple cores that will execute the threads simultaneously. And even if your computer only had one processor, your operating system time-slices the execution of all different threads automatically to achieve the same effect. Also, if you look at the output above, "Type something" is printed BEFORE the first "Hello", so `Thread.sleep` hasn't even happened yet.